# Java: possible transformation of List of objects to List of strings

Tags: java, guava

I have a bunch of manager classes which manage different objects like state, country and so on. `getObjects()` method returns a list of such objects, values of these lists are appended in different methods like the following ones:

```
//states - StateManager.java
public String getStateMsg() {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    if (states != null) {
        for (State state : states.getObjects()) {
            msg.append(state.getStateCd())).append(" ");
        }
    }
    return msg.toString().trim();
}

//codes - CodeManager.java
public String getCodeMsg() {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    if (codes != null) {
        for (Code code :  codes.getObjects()) {
            msg.append(code.getCd()).append(" ");
        }
    }
    return msg.toString().trim();
}

//countries - CountryManager.java
public String getCountriesMsg() {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    if (countries != null) {
        for (Country country : countries.getObjects()) {
            msg.append(countries.get(country.getCountryCd())).append(" ");
        }
    }
    return msg.toString().trim();
}
```

There's obvious code duplication and I want to make general solution where a method takes a collection (retrieved by `getObjects()`) and returns a list of strings.

I found that guava can make some sort of collection transformations from one type to another. But classes in the example (State, Code, Country) do not share any general interface. From the other hand, a method which will take collection of objects and method name to retrieve value of a specific object field, means usage of reflection that isn't a good idea.

As a result I have a question, is it possible to avoid described code duplication and make a utility method which will take collection of objects and return collection of strings?

Comment: Are you able to create an interface for `State`, `Code`, `Country`? If they all have the same general method `getCd()`, then an interface of some sort probably makes sense.

Comment: Do you have Java 8?  If so, it's easy.  If not, you're not going to get significantly better than this.

Comment: First of all, don't allow Lists to be null. Just take an empty List. Then take a look at Lists.transform() and the Joiner Class from Guava

Comment: @Hypino, some of the classes cannot be modified (Code for example). What I know is the method name which retrieves needed data for further append.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I use Java 7 at the moment, but I'm thinking on migration to Java 8 in the nearest future.

Comment: @LouisWasserman why not a generic functional method?

Comment: @OmarHrynkiewicz, because the boilerplate for the functional code will be at least as long as the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have Java 8, use generics and [Guava Function](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained):

```java
public static <T, U> String getGenericMsg(List<T> genericList, Function<T, U> function) {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    if (genericList != null) {
        for (T genericObject : genericList) {
            msg.append(function.apply(genericObject)).append(" ");
        }
    }
    return msg.toString().trim();
}


private static Function<State, String> STATE_TO_STRING = new Function<State, String>() {
    public String apply(State input) {
        return input.getStateCd();
    }
};

private static Function<Code, String> CODE_TO_STRING = new Function<Code, String>() {
    public String apply(Code input) {
        return input.getCd();
    }
};

private static Function<Country, String> COUNTRY_TO_STRING = new Function<Country, String>() {
    public String apply(Country input) {
        return input.getCountryCd();
    }
};
```

Finally your client code:

```java
public void yourClientMethod() {
    getGenericMsg(states, STATE_TO_STRING);
    getGenericMsg(codes, CODE_TO_STRING);
    getGenericMsg(countries, COUNTRY_TO_STRING);
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I definitely need to practice more with guava.